# CodeIgniter executes database queries in the wrong order (maybe parallel?)

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using the current version of CodeIgniter (2.1.3). I have three MySQL Tables:

### MySQL Tables

#### operator

```
id  name
========
1   ACME
```

#### tag

```
id  tag
=======
1   bar
2   foo
```

#### operator_tag

```
id  operator_id  tag_id
=======================
1   1            1
2   1            2
```

So the operator ACME is tagged with both tags (bar and foo).

### CodeIgniter Files

I get an error while trying to remove a tag like this:

```php
//file: controllers/tag.php (function contained in class Tag extends CI_Controller)

//this function should remove the tag with the id $id and redirect back to the edit page for the operator
public function remove($id){
    $operator_id = $this->operator_model->get_operator_for_tag_id($id);
    $this->operator_model->remove_tag_from_operator($id);
    redirect('operator/edit/'.$operator_id);
}
```

..

```php
//file: models/operator_model.php (functions contained in class Operator_model extends CI_Model)

public function get_operator_for_tag_id($id){
    $query = $this->db->select('operator_id')->from('operator_tag')->where('id',$id)->get();
    return $query->row()->operator_id;
}

public function remove_tag_from_operator($id){
    $this->db->delete('operator_tag',array('id' => $id));
}
```

### Error

If I call the function to remove the tag "foo" (id:2) from the operator, I open the url http://example.com/tag/remove/2 (which successfully calls the controller "tag" -> function "remove" with the parameter "2". However most of the time I receive the following error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: models/operator_model.php
Line Number: XX (which is line with `return $query->row()->operator_id;`)
```

It seems, that the DELETE query is executed before the SELECT query. (I tried to add an INSERT query in the (second) `remove_tag_from_operator` function and echoed all results of this table in the (first) `get_operator_for_tag_id` function which mysteriously included the row (previously generated) in the delete function.

Does CodeIgniter execute the queries parallel, or ques them in any special order? If so, is there any possibility to disable this? Thanks in advance!

## Edit 1: Echo values @luc

@luc I changed the code to the following (added echo lines) for debugging:

```php
//file: controllers/tag.php
public function remove($id){
    echo '-1. CONTROLLER '.$id.'<br>';
    $operator_id = $this->operator_model->get_operator_for_tag_id($id);
    echo '-2. CONTROLLER '.$id.'<br>';
    $this->operator_model->remove_tag_from_operator($id);
    echo '-3. CONTROLLER '.$id.'<br>';
    redirect('operator/edit/'.$operator_id);
}
```

```php
//file: models/operator_model.php
public function get_operator_for_tag_id($id)
{
    echo '-1.1 GET '.$id.'<br>';
    $query = $this->db->select('operator_id')->from('operator_tag')->where('id',$id)->get();
    echo '-1.2 GET '.$id.'<br>';
    $result = $query->row()->operator_id;
    echo '-1.3 GET '.$id.'<br>';
    return $result;
}

public function remove_tag_from_operator($id){
    echo '-2.1 REMOVE '.$id.'<br>';
    $this->db->delete('operator_tag',array('id' => $id));
    echo '-2.2 REMOVE '.$id.'<br>';
}
```

which outputs something like the following on calling http://example.com/tag/remove/41

```
-1. CONTROLLER 41  
-1.1 GET 41  
-1.2 GET 41  

**A PHP Error was encountered**  
Severity: Notice  
Message: Trying to get property of non-object  
Filename: models/operator_model.php
Line Number: 236 (which is the row with `$result = $query->row()->operator_id;`)

-1.3 GET 41  
-2. CONTROLLER 41  
-2.1 REMOVE 41  
-2.2 REMOVE 41  
-3. CONTROLLER 41  

**A PHP Error was encountered**  
Severity: Warning  
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .../application/controllers/tag.php:242)  (which is the output generated by `echo '1. CONTROLLER '.$id.'<br>';`)
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php  
Line Number: 542
```

So the $id is passed correctly and the echoes are in the correct order. Only the database queries are executed in an mysterious way.

## Edit 2: Check rows @itachi

@itachi I changed the following code for debugging (output the whole operator_tag-table if value is not found)

```php
//file: controllers/tag.php
public function get_operator_for_tag_id($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('operator_id')->from('operator_tag')->where('id',$id)->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->row()->operator_id;
    }else{
        $query = $this->db->get('operator_tag');
        print_r($query->result());
    }
}
```

which outputs something like the following on calling http://example.com/tag/remove/44

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [operator_id] => 40 [tag_id] => 1 ) )
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .../application/models/operator_model.php:236) (which is the line with `print_r($query->result());`)
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
Line Number: 542
```

I tried to reproduce the working example but I failed. If I comment out the `$this->db->delete('operator_tag',array('id' => $id));` line it works (redirects me to operator/edit/$id).

Comment: you said **most of the time** Does it mean above code works at times? If yes, do you noticed any pattern when it works? 2nd, if you comment out the `delete` query from above code, does it returns the id without any error message?

Comment: In `operator_tag`, why do both rows have an `id` of `1`?

Comment: -itachi if I comment out the delete block it always works (redirects me back to operator/edit/$id). Yes, the code works some times. I was not able to recognize a pattern.  I will edit the main post, to post another code sample.
-RocketHazmat Sorry, that was only a typo. The second row of course should have an id of 2 (I fixed this).

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs mostly because the query string is incomplete. Do you have a $this->uri->segment(3) somewhere to fetch the $id? I don't see it in your code. Where is $id defined?

Try to echo its value, I think that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. AFAIK the segments automatically get passed as the parameters so CodeIgniter maps http://example.com/tag/remove/2 to the controller "tag", the function "remove" and passes the parameter "2". That worked always before. However I successfully echoed the id.

Answer (score 0):

I always got the same error (Trying to get property of non-object) and **could not manage to create a scenario where the code *works***.

So I tried to flush the table. The first rows were deleted as expected. On deleting (about id = 9 or so) I received the same error on and on (no chance to get it working again).

I flushed the table again and now I **could not manage to reproduce the *error*** again. I tried this procedure about 5 times with around 40 inserts/deletes each.

I never experienced a bug like this. Maybe the database/table was corrupted? Maybe there are settings for the MySQL-Server for "performance improvements" like multiple threads? Maybe it is the fault of the host (For a time I got many HTTP 500 errors, which redirected to a /404 page of the host himself when I forgot a semicolon or something like that). Anyway, as my client wants to keep his odd host I have no option.

Thank you all, for your great and fast support!